# Can't remove header on BlankSlate for wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

I'm drafting a website and since I needed a minimal theme with no header and no footer I picked up BlankSlate. I managed to get rid of the footer the easy way but when it comes to the header, I'm stuck. Here's my website temp location http://95.179.181.250

The header.php file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
<header id="header">
<div id="branding">
<div id="site-title">
<?php if ( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_front_page() && is_home() ) { echo '<h1>'; } ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php echo esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?></a>
<?php if ( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_front_page() && is_home() ) { echo '</h1>'; } ?>
</div>
<div id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></div>
</div>
<nav id="menu">
<div id="search"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav>
</header>
<div id="container">
```

I tried to tweak it but I might be missing the point. Whatever I do I end up with a buggy page.

Could you help me on this ?

Comment: What exactly are you “stuck” with then? If you don’t want the header, then remove everything from `<header id="header">` to `</header>`? What was the result when you tried, and how did it differ from what you expected?

Comment: as suggested in addition to removing the header from `<header id = "header">` to `</header>`
under
`<div id = "container"> <main id = "content"> <article id = "post-5" class = "post-5 page type-page status-publish hentry"> <header class = "header">`

there is this other header which is the last white line with the three dots ...
You can probably do it from the backend of the wordpress theme, right?

Comment: @04FS when I remove everything as suggested, I end up with new white spaces on top and bottom of my sliders (which should cover the whole height). http://www.imagebam.com/image/734c3d1331904046

Comment: @Nobady. I'm trying to find out in the backend of wordpress. The theme doesn't have specific options unfortunately.

Comment: Solved. I'm now using another theme.